# How to refesh a list view in android

Tags: android, android-listview

In my listActivity , I am using

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.project_list, titles));
```

to set my list view. now I want to sort this list on click of spinner for that i am using like it

```
spn_sort_order .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }

   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
```

and to display the new results I need to refresh the old view.

**Edit:**

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                    sortBy = position;
                    System.out.println("selected item id:::priortiy::::"
                            + sortBy);
                    if (sortBy == 1) {
                        Collections.sort(titles);
                        System.out.println(titles);
                        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    if (sortBy == 2) {
                        Comparator<Object> comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
                        Collections.sort(titles,comparator);
                        System.out.println(titles);
                        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }
```

when i click on first item in the list my data is sorted in ascending order and when i click on second item in the list data is sorted in descending order bcoz i used

```
Comparator<Object> comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're using an `ArrayAdapter` so I would recommend using `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @Romi: no...it will automatically change!

Comment: the ArrayAdapter is used to bind the data set to the listView, so if you want to sort the listView, you have to sort the data in the adapter and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to request the system to refresh the listView based on your new data set. Or you can just set a new ArrayAdapter via setListAdapter().

Answer (score 0):

try listView.invalidate()     .       .;

Comment: would you give me some detail please

Comment: Wouldn't this just *redraw* the Spinner without it ever knowing that the data has been changed?

Comment: @Shailendra Rajawat -  Do you know the proper use of listView.invalidate()? where to use it?

Comment: yes . whenever you know there is some change in list data and want to reflect on screen use it .this will recreate the list by calling getView() for every child

Comment: Then what is difference between listView.invalidate() and Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?

Answer (score 0):

When I tested your code, I found it works.

```
package viewTest.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ViewTestActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter0;
    private String[] array0;
    private ListView lv0;       
    private ArrayList<String> array;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
//Content on LV0.xml: A, B, C,D
        array0 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LV0);
        array=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<array0.length;i++)
            array.add(array0[i]);


        adapter0 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, array);    
        lv0 = new ListView(this);

        lv0.setAdapter(adapter0);


//When clicking any item of the listview, the listview will referesh the content to: D,C,B,A
        lv0.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


                Comparator<Object> comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
                Collections.sort(array,comparator);
//              lv0.invalidate(); //This call won't refresh the content.
                adapter0.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
        setContentView(lv0);
    }

}
```

Here, I found a strange thing. When clicking on an item for the second time, the content would not be reversed to be :A,B,C,D. It seems that the array is reversed only once. Any Idea? I am not a professional programmer.

Comment: Huang: i appreciate your efforts :), look at my edit, this is wrking fine.